# Facebook widget (by Milap Patel) how to translate the text?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, widget

im using the facebook widget for wordpress by: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-pagelike-widget/
on my blog, but I would like to translate or change the text that currently says "Find us on Facebook". Is that posible?

Ive search through the plugin folder and its files but im not experienced enough or its just not there. please help if posible.

Answer (score 1):

In the plugin folder you can edit the file named fb.js on line 7:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="+appid;
```

Change **en_US** to the locale you want. The full list of available Facebook locales can be found here: https://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml

The problem with doing this will be the locale will switch back to en_US if you install an update to the plugin. I would get your own embed code from Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) and paste it into your theme or a HTML widget for your sidebar.